# Generate possible solutions to image captcha from a list of each class with confidence

Tags: python, artificial-intelligence, captcha, yolov5

I have a YOLOV5 model that uses object detection to solve captchas. It returns a list in the format:

```
<object-class> <x> <y> <width> <height> <confidence>
```

and for every class detection.

Example:

Input:

[image: 1]

Output:

```
[[
['7l', 0.19, '0.443182', '0.104895', '0.431818', '0.972055'], 
['4l', 0.33, '0.534091', '0.104895', '0.431818', '0.965045'], 
['5l', 0.6, '0.238636', '0.118881', '0.431818', '0.974508'], 
['9l', 0.92, '0.659091', '0.104895', '0.409091', '0.879532'], 
['0l', 0.93, '0.659091', '0.0979021', '0.363636', '0.651053']
]]
```

As you can see, the classes 9l and 0l have the same x value meaning the model has two answers for one object.

How can I split this list into two possible lists like:

`7l 4l 5l 9l`
and
`7l 4l 5l 0l`

Comment: maybe first convert to dictionary `{"'0.443182'": ["7l"], ..., "'0.659091'": ["0l", "9l"]}` and later use nested `for`-loop to generate all combinations. OR use it with `itertools.product` like `for item in itertools.product(['7l'], ['9l','0l'])` to get `('7l', '9l'), ('7l', '0l')`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First you can convert data to dictionary

```
{'0.443182': ['7l'], '0.534091': ['4l'], '0.238636': ['5l'], '0.659091': ['9l', '0l']}
```

Next get only values

```
[['7l'], ['4l'], ['5l'], ['9l', '0l']]
```

And finally use `itertools.product(['7l'], ['4l'], ['5l'], ['9l', '0l'])` to generate

```
('7l', '4l', '5l', '9l')
('7l', '4l', '5l', '0l')
```

---

Full working code.

Because standard dictionary doesn't have to keep order so I use `OrderedDict()`

```
import collections
import itertools

data = [[
['7l', 0.19, '0.443182', '0.104895', '0.431818', '0.972055'], 
['4l', 0.33, '0.534091', '0.104895', '0.431818', '0.965045'], 
['5l', 0.6, '0.238636', '0.118881', '0.431818', '0.974508'], 
['9l', 0.92, '0.659091', '0.104895', '0.409091', '0.879532'], 
['0l', 0.93, '0.659091', '0.0979021', '0.363636', '0.651053']
]]

#converted = {}
converted = collections.OrderedDict()

for item in data[0]:
    class_ = item[0]
    x      = item[2]
    #if x not in converted:
    #    converted[x] = []
    #converted[x].append(class_)
    converted.setdefault(x, []).append(class_)
        
print('converted:', converted)

values = list(converted.values())

print('values:', values)

products = list(itertools.product(*values))
print('products:', products)

for item in products:
    print('item:', "".join(item))
```

Result:

```
converted: OrderedDict([('0.443182', ['7l']), ('0.534091', ['4l']), ('0.238636', ['5l']), ('0.659091', ['9l', '0l'])])
values: [['7l'], ['4l'], ['5l'], ['9l', '0l']]
products: [('7l', '4l', '5l', '9l'), ('7l', '4l', '5l', '0l')]
item: 7l4l5l9l
item: 7l4l5l0l
```

Comment: What if the x values were close but not exact. For example, 0.92 and 0.93.

Comment: it may need to define ranges and create many `if/else` to check values - `if 0.9 < x <= 1.0: converted[ "0.9-1.0" ] = ...`. Eventually you can try to use some functions in `numpy` or `pandas` to split in ranges - something like in `histogram` or `bin`